# Anaconda auto-complete for Python does not work

Tags: python, autocomplete, anaconda

I am programming in Python (in Sublime Text 3) and auto-complete feature works for 90% of the modules. Modules like os, sys, unittest...

But now I am trying to use modules like `selenium` and `numpy` and they don't have auto-complete feature.

I am using Anaconda (`conda`) package distribution and I am using `Anaconda ST3 Plugin`. Also tried something called (a plugin) `Selenium Snippets`. None of that helps.

Please, any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Juris.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that Anaconda has it's own package manager. 
So you should install on it the external package you want to work with.

Try something like this on your terminal:

```
conda install -c conda-forge PLUGINNAME=PLUGINVERSION
```

You can find a list of plugins and versions available here (after searching, look for `conda forge`:
https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/repo

Versions ref: 
1. Selenium - https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/selenium/files
2. Numpy - https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/numpy/files

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks. This is not the problem actually. I have Anaconda all setup and installed. I use Python 3.6 from there: 

print(sys.version)
print(sys.executable)

3.6.6 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Oct  9 2018, 12:34:16) 
[GCC 7.3.0]
/media/Work/anaconda3/bin/python

And I did install all the modules from there. But the problem is, Sublime Text does not pick up auto-complete for those packages, from Anaconda. Nor does the Atom. Auto-complete feature works for some base packages, but not for Anaconda packages like numpy or selenium.

Comment: @YuriyLaivins, have you installed the packages on `conda-forge`, though?

Comment: Or maybe the issue is that you haven't installed the libs directly from pip, @YuriyLaivins, and if this is the case, you might be able to run the modules from `conda` folder, but `ST3` is not recognising the path to you modules

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me out! So the problem is, I seem to have everything installed correctly. When I install using conda, for some reason it automatically appears in a list of packages of pip. Sublime still does not pick this one up. I have tried Atom editor, same thing. Please see the link: https://pastebin.com/1yLahz21

Comment: I mean, I can use the libs, it all works, but not having auto-complete for some of the libs I need, and the more complicated ones, is a big problem as I am only starting to use them.

Comment: I have installed PyCharm and it asked me where my Python is, I showed it my anaconda folder, it scanned all installed packages and works perfectly, auto-completes all the code from all the modules. So I need a way to make this work on Sublime Text some how...so it can build a cash of all installed libs and pick up all the info for auto-complete to work....

Answer (score 0):

OK. This is sorted by Trial and Error. Basically, I had to point my `Sublime Text` `Anaconda Plugin` to my `Anaconda Package Managers` path. I have edited the settings for `Anaconda` plugin and set the path like that:

"python_interpreter": "/media/Work/anaconda3/bin/python",

After that, it picked up all the packages from `Anaconda (Conda)`

Thanks!